# retracting :db/ident from an entity

Tags: clojure, datomic

I have a bunch of entities that are special, but they are not part of the db schema. Since these entities are special I set some `:db/ident` attributes to them to have easy access to them in my programs.

Lets say I call one of these accounts `:base-account` Now the problem is that when I use entity api to access these entities I have this problem:

```
;; access some entity that references one of the special entities
> (d/touch (d/entity db 12345678))
==> 
{:transaction/amount 22334455,
 :transaction/from {:db/id 0987654}, ;; normal reference to an entity
 :transaction/to :base-account} ;; this is a reference to a special account with a :db/ident attribute
```

This causes me problems in some of the code I have written before, because this will not give me the details of the `:transaction/to` account.

So to solve this problem I removed the `:db/ident` attributes from these entities:

```
> (d/transact connection [[:db/retract id-of-the-special-account
                           :db/ident :base-account]])
```

Which successfully removes the `:db/ident` from the entity:

```
> (:db/ident (d/entity db id-of-the-special-account))
==> nil
```

But for some reason (maybe a bug), the entity api call still refers to it with its old identity:

```
> (d/entity db :base-account) ;; should not work
==> {:db/id id-of-the-special-account}
```

So how can I remove the identity from these entities without having to remove them from the database altogether? Or maybe a way to fix the way the `(d/entity ....)` call works, in a sane way?

EDIT: I'm using datomic-pro-5544

Comment: This might be a silly question, but I have to ask. Are you using the same `db` value as before transacting the retraction? This happens to me more than I'd like to admit in the REPL... Especially when changing data through another channel (like compojure) and using a stale db in the REPL and scratching my head as to why the data is still there...

Comment: @KennethKalmer I know what you mean, to avoid that problem I have a little `(db)` function that I use, which always gets the latest value of the db. I just didn't write it in the codes above to to avoid having to explain it ;)

Comment: This is wrecking my brain, and I really want to give a good answer... What is the `valueType` of `:transaction/to`? Is it a `:db.type/ref`? Could it be that the transactions themselves still hold references to the `:base-account` ident? Did you update the values of `:transaction/to` to be ref-ed by `:db/id`?

Comment: @KennethKalmer `:transaction/to` and `:transaction/from` are both reference types, and I think ref types always have the value of the `:db/id` of the target entity. I can test this with `(d/pull (db) '[*] id-of-some-transaction)` which gives me the results in this format: `{:db/id ... :transaction/amount ... :transaction/from {:db/id ...} :transaction/to {:db/id ...}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Datomic Docs](http://docs.datomic.com/identity.html):

> Idents should be used for two purposes: to name schema entities and to
>   implement enumerated tags. Both of these uses are demonstrated in the
>   introductory tutorial. To support these usages, idents have two
>   special characteristics:
>
> - Idents are designed to be extremely fast and always available. All idents associated with a database are stored in memory in every
>     Datomic transactor and peer.
> - When you navigate the entity API to a reference that has an ident, the lookup will return the ident, not another entity.

That last bullet point might be what is affecting you.

Next paragraph:

> These characteristics also imply situations where idents should not be
>   used:
>
> - Idents should not be used as unique names or ids on ordinary domain entities. Such entity names should be implemented with a
>     domain-specific attribute that is a unique identity.
> - Idents should not be used as names for test data. (Your real data will not have such names, and you don't want test data to behave
>     differently than the real data it simulates.)

From this it seems like you might want to re-design the DB, rather than trying to un-do your use of `:db/ident`.